# Local server not reflecting updated files

Tags: node.js, phaser-framework, httpserver

I'm fairly new at user local servers. I'm using the http-server which is a package from Node. I'm using it to host an HTML5 game using the Phaser library. I have image assets I'm using in the game, and I sometimes update these assets. When I do, the changes to the images aren't reflected in the game. I've tried restarting the server but that doesn't help. It usually takes some time for them to update, maybe about an hour. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The browser might be caching your code and/or assets.

In Chrome, with dev tools open (Right click -> Inspect element) you can right click on the refresh button and 'empty cache and hard reload'.

Comment: Thank you. Why does that happen only occasionally?

Answer (score 24):

There's an option `-c` that refers to the cache time (max-age) in seconds [3600]

(e.g. `-c10` for 10 seconds).

To disable caching, use `http-server -c-1`

You can see more information by enter `http-server -h` (for help)

Comment: This solution is the sure-shot solution. It forces the server to update any changes you make immediately.

Comment: This is unix only command, right? I work on Windows. What do I do?

Comment: c-1 says it is -1 seconds and it did not work for me. What did the trick was c-01, which is 1 second.

Comment: @PepeAlvarez, c-01 is still -1 second for me.  I did http-server -c01 or http-server -c1, both produce 1 second.

Answer (score 15):

You can disable cache in Chrome DevTools under "Network".

Whenever you reload a page while DevTools is open, it will clear the cache.

---

Alternatively, use the hard refresh keyboard shortcut (Mac):
<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

[image: disable cache button in chrome devtools]

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use `live-server` instead. It works for me.

```
npm install live-server -g
```

And you can start it simply by the command `live-server`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your html file is in the correct location. A couple of times I've been editing my html and js files and then at some point I might cut and paste the files into a new folder. I'll change the reference to the new directory. But I forget that I need to reopen the html and js files from the new directory. Instead I keep editing them from the old directory and refreshing the browser wondering why nothing is changing. It's because the files I'm editing are the versions in the old directory. I need to close them and then open the files that are in the new directory.